# Make (integromat) "Watch Updates" module for Telegram Bot not working since yesterday

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, make.com

The module "Watch Updates" (webhook) since yesterday started returning only the ID of the updates, with every other field empty (message text, message ID, everything else).
Tried with different bots created with 2 different accounts (1 premium and 1 standard), and same result: empty update except for the update ID.
The "List Updates" module works fine and gives me everything for some reason. This is not an issue of having a webhook active while calling the List Updates method.
Every time I activate a "Watch Updates" module I dont use the "List Updates" module anymore.
This isssue started yesterday, how can I fix it?
(I tried with bot privacy enabled and disabled, in different group chats)

Answer (score 1):

Accessing to webhook's Logs, it's possible to see that in "Parsed Items", message is `null` even though is present in "Body".
So I think that module's parser is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: This fix worked for 10 minutes and stopped working. It may have been a coincidence that it worked when I changed the privacy setting.  I'm leaving this post here for a while in case it helps someone else.**

I had the same problem, and it started this morning. Communicating directly with the bot results in an "(empty)" message coming through in Integromat/Make, just as you described.

The bot privacy setting you mentioned seemed to work for me as a workaround. After turning off "Group Privacy" and deleting the chat, conversations with the bot started having a proper message field again (instead of just the update id).

1. Head over to [botfather](https://t.me/BotFather)
2. Type "/mybots"
3. Select your bot from the list
4. Select "Bot Settings"
5. Select "Group Privacy"
6. Select "Turn off"

You might need to delete your conversation with your bot for this to take effect.

NB! There are privacy implications to turning this setting off. If you add or re-add the bot to any groups once this setting is off, the bot will receive all messages from members of that group. This may not be what you want.
[More info here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/features#privacy-mode)